# Get radio button checked value jquery version 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

I have set of radio button having name rdoSearchBy.I wnat to get the checked value wrt its name.below is my html code

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoPurchaseDate" runat="server" value="purchaseDate" Text="Purchase Date"
                                                Checked="true" GroupName="rdoSearchBy" name="rdoSearchBy" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoReceiveDate" runat="server" value="receiveDate" Text="Receive Date"
                                                GroupName="rdoSearchBy" name="rdoSearchBy" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Below is my jquery code

```
var sortingParameter = $("input[name='rdoSearchBy']:checked").val();
```

But the above code is not working.I am using 1.9.1 version of jquery

Can anybody help me please..

Comment: Can you produce a fiddle that reproduces the problem? I suspect that an `asp:RadioButton` != `input`?

Comment: Any error in the console? jquery is loaded or undefined.

Comment: Could you show us the generated HTML in a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to assign `var sortingParameter` when the radio button isn't checked, so the selector doesn't match anything. Attach a change handler to it, check if it's checked, and if it is, assign it to `sortingParameter`.

Comment: @sandeep.mishra What is undefined the value or jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as below sample

HTML

```
    <input type="radio" id="edit-filter-1" name="rdoSearchBy" value="1" class="form-radio">
    <label class="option" for="edit-filter-1">One</label>

    <input type="radio" id="edit-filter-2" name="rdoSearchBy" value="2" class="form-radio">
    <label class="option" for="edit-filter-2">Two</label>
```

Js

```
$('input[name="rdoSearchBy"]').change(function(){
    alert($('input[name="rdoSearchBy"]:checked').val());
});
```

use this

```
$('input[name$="rdoSearchBy"]').change(function(){
    alert($('input[name$="rdoSearchBy"]:checked').val());
});
```

`name$` will search `rdoSearchBy` as `last string` in `name` attribute
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AKGYB/1/)

Comment: I am working on a asp:radio button

Comment: @sandeep.mishra all controls will render in `html`. For more help provide `Generated Html`

Comment: Below is generated html when rendered
 <span name="rdoSearchBy"><input id="rdoPurchaseDate" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$rdoSearchBy" value="purchaseDate" checked="checked" /><label for="rdoPurchaseDate">Purchase Date</label></span>

Answer (score -1):

Dont use `''` only write

`var sortingParameter = $("input[name=rdoSearchBy]:checked").val()`;